# How to apply rolling or expanding transformations to datetime data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rolling-computation

I want to calculate expanding maximum  `expanding().max()` for datetime column but get the error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Is there any way to apply functions `expanding` and `rolling` with further transformations to datetime data? For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": ['05/01/2021', '05/03/2021', '05/02/2021', '05/04/2021']})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

        time
0 2021-05-01
1 2021-05-03
2 2021-05-02
3 2021-05-04

df.time.expanding().max()
# DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Desired result:

```
0 2021-05-01
1 2021-05-03
2 2021-05-03
3 2021-05-04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html):

```
df.time.cummax()
```

to get

```
0   2021-05-01
1   2021-05-03
2   2021-05-03
3   2021-05-04
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```